# empty php file downloads sometimes when i use the site

Tags: php, apache, connection

I am using amazon ec2 server Centos ...

The site is working fine but when many connections are requested the script halts and an empty php file is downloading.. ?

Can anyone tell me the reason..?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try increasing the maximum execution time in the php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 6000
```